# printing a tibble or data frame in an interactive user input with select.list

Tags: r, interactive

I want to capture some user input in the R console. Along with capturing the user input I want to print a tibble that helps the user decide which input to select. Here's a simple example:

```
library(tidyverse)
input <- tibble(color = c("blue", "green"),
                words = c("test", "hello"))
                
utils::select.list(c(as.character(c("Yes", "No"))),
                     title = print(c(input, "\nDo all words contain letters?")),
                     multiple = FALSE)
```

This obviously doesn't work since select.list says:

> 'title' must be NULL or a length-1 character vector

So question is how I could print the tibble along with the question/message and capture teh user input. Happy to use sth. else than `select.input`.

The ideal print would be sth. like:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  color words
  <chr> <chr>
1 blue  test 
2 green hello

Do all words contain letters?

1: Yes
2: No
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap in a function, as below:

```
f <- function(tbl) {
  print(tbl)
  cat("\n")
  utils::select.list(
    c(as.character(c("Yes", "No"))),
    title = "Do all words contain letters?",
    multiple = FALSE)
}
```

Usage

```
f(input)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  color words
  <chr> <chr>
1 blue  test 
2 green hello

Do all words contain letters? 

1: Yes
2: No
```

Comment: perfect. Wrapping it into a fucntion makes sense and works nicely. Thanks!